# Trying to copy features from an in_memory table to feature table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, in-memory

i just want to write the in_memory table to a table in a .gdb

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
import sys
scriptPath = sys.path[0]
thisFolder = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(scriptPath))
env.workspace = os.path.join(thisFolder, "AdminReport", "Workspace")

#get variables
...code here..

#create Table
print("Creating Table...")
tempTable = arcpy.CreateTable_management("in_memory", "tempTable")
arcpy.AddField_management(tempTable, "Parcel_FID", "LONG")
arcpy.AddField_management(tempTable, "Plan_Acres", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(tempTable, "Pres_Acres", "DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(tempTable, "Conf_Region", "TEXT", field_length=25)
arcpy.AddField_management(tempTable, "Conf_Date", "TEXT", field_length=25)
arcpy.AddField_management(tempTable, "Center_Zone", "TEXT", field_length=25)
arcpy.AddField_management(tempTable, "Center_Muni", "TEXT", field_length=25)

#calculate values for each field
row = arcpy.InsertCursor(tempTable).newRow()
row.setValue("Parcel_FID", objectID)
row.setValue("Plan_Acres", planAcres)
row.setValue("Pres_Acres", presAcres)
row.setValue("Conf_Region", confRegion)
row.setValue("Conf_Date", confDate)
row.setValue("Center_Zone", centerZone)
row.setValue("Center_Muni", centerMuni)
del row

#Output Table to GDB
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(tempTable, "Workspace.gdb", "outTable")
```

No errors but I am geting an empty table generated.

Comment: You have already created your table and have added rows to it, so that's not the problem. In addition to using "Copy Features" on a table you're also trying to copy those features (table columns?) to...itself. What is your end goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing inserting the row in your insert cursor.

Try this code instead for the cursor:

```
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(tempTable)
row = cursor.newRow()
row.setValue("Parcel_FID", objectID)
row.setValue("Plan_Acres", planAcres)
row.setValue("Pres_Acres", presAcres)
row.setValue("Conf_Region", confRegion)
row.setValue("Conf_Date", confDate)
row.setValue("Center_Zone", centerZone)
row.setValue("Center_Muni", centerMuni)
cursor.insertRow(row)

del cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `outTable` is a result object. Apparently this works for `AddField_management`, but not `CopyFeatures_management`. A string of the path will work for all code.

Change:

`outTable = arcpy.CreateTable_management("in_memory", "outTable")`

to:

`outTable = arcpy.CreateTable_management("in_memory", "outTable").getOutput (0)`

See [the Result help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000046000000).

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpPk42Flr7g&list=PLdhJ6K9-pcjO3GZXybh7InOm1-CIVVpS7&index=7) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1imV-9D9t4&list=PLdhJ6K9-pcjO3GZXybh7InOm1-CIVVpS7&index=8) are good tutorial videos too.

Also, instead of `CopyFeatures_management`, you might want to try [Copy](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//001700000051000000) or [Table To Table](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000027000000).

Comment: does CreateTable_management copy all of the records in the "in_memory" table? This doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: Create Table creates a table with no rows.

Comment: ok i have updated my code to give you a better idea of what I am attempting to do. I need to end up with a table that has 1 row of values.

Comment: arcpy.TableToTable_conversion generates an empty table for some reason